# Referring to "this" without using .each()

Tags: jquery

I have an element `$myElement` that I want to refer to using `this` inside `.css()` call. Specifically, I tried to change the CSS property `someCssProperty` to `$myElement.myProperty` naively:

> $myElement.css(someCssProperty, this.myProperty);

Is there a way of having a working `this` without using the cumbersome `.each()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[css](http://api.jquery.com/css) takes a function as a parameter which you can use:

```
$myElement.css(someCssProperty, function(index, value) {
    return this.myProperty;
});
```

The callback also receives the index in the set and the old value as parameters.